# convert rows to columns in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table in database that looks like:

[image]

I am trying to create query which gives me result like:

[image]

And when I was searching trough the forum I did found information about converting rows to columns using aggregate function and/or using predefined statement. From example what I did found I did try following queries however they doesn't work I don't understand how they work so I simply copy the query. I did try to use my data in it:

```
select fk_playerID as name, roundID as roundNo, score
from(
roundID,
CASE WHEN roundID = 1 THEN score END AS 1,
CASE WHEN roundID = 2 THEN score END AS 2,
CASE WHEN roundID = 3 THEN score END AS 3,
from cup
) cup group by fk_playerID
```

and the second one:

```
SELECT fk_playerID as name, roundID as roundNo, score
MAX(CASE WHEN'roundID' = 1, THEN score end) roundNo1,
MAX(CASE WHEN'roundID' = 2, THEN score end) roundNo2,
MAX(CASE WHEN'roundID' = 3, THEN score end) roundNo3
FROM cup
ORDER BY fk_playerID
```

And finally my question is how my query must look like and also I need a little explanation how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one is pretty close:

```
SELECT c.fk_playerID,
       p.Name
       MAX(CASE WHEN c.roundID = 1 THEN c.score END) AS roundNo1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN c.roundID = 2 THEN c.score END) AS roundNo2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN c.roundID = 3 THEN c.score END) AS roundNo3
FROM cup c
JOIN Player p on c.fk_playerID = p.ID
GROUP BY c.fk_playerID, p.Name
```

You are grouping by `fk_playerID`. Lets consider `player = 1`. This

```
CASE WHEN roundID = 1 THEN score END
```

will produce the following set for `score`: `{1, null, null}`. Max will return 1.

```
CASE WHEN roundID = 2 THEN score END
```

will produce the following set for `score`: `{null, 1, null}`. Max will return 1.

```
CASE WHEN roundID = 3 THEN score END
```

will produce the following set for `score`: `{null, null, 1}`. Max will return 1.

The same for `player = 19`.

Comment: Thank you! can you give me a little explanation what this statement actually do so I will understand it and I will be able to use it again when I will have similar problem. And if for example I want to join table 'Players' to get the player name i will join table before MAX or after so the query will give same result + player name ??

Comment: Fantastic answer Thank You Giorgi Nakeuri